# Get instance of a running timer in java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

Is it possible to get the instance of a running timer in Java?

More precisely, what I want to do is get a current running timer by name and cancel it. How can I do this?

I tried referring it as a Thread and convert it to Timer, but it wasn't allowed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm almost sure you don't want to kill the `Timer` itself, but a `TimerTask` that has been scheduled for repeated execution. Am I right?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are starting the Timer?

Comment: Can you give more info about your context? What are you using the timers and tasks for, why do you want to cancel them, and what types of things currently trigger their cancellation?

Answer (score 0):

A `Timer` has an *associated* thread (optionally with a name). It's not a thread itself, so your attempt to cast `Thread` to a `Timer` fails.

The documentation for `Timer` does not indicate that a way to look up a timer by name is provided. Furthermore, if you look at the [source for `Timer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Timer.java), you'll see that no global "registration" of any sort takes place, i.e. there does not exist some map of timer names to timers somewhere. Therefore what you ask is not possible.

Instead, you will have to consider alternate approaches in your design. For example, keep track of your `TimerTask`s properly and [cancel those](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel()) as necessary. This would make the most sense. I suppose you could also store a map of timer names to timers somewhere, but if you need to resort to this it implies you've conceptually lost the connection between `TimerTask`s and the things that manage specific tasks somewhere, which could indicate a design issue. You may also choose to use e.g. a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), so that you just have to keep track of `Runnables` (with just one central `ExecutorService` to manage) rather than having to track individual timers *and* tasks (at the cost of not having the handy `TimerTask.cancel()` available) -- this may or may not ease design.